# How to restart a service with VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Ok, so I'm new to VB.NET and trying to write a program that prompts the user for a server name and then restarts the IIS on that machine.

Problem 1) namespace `System.ServiceProcess` is not being recognized.
Problem 2) need help with code, passing servername into sub.

```
Imports System
Imports System.ServiceProcess
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading

Class RestartIIS
    Shared Sub Main()
        Run()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Run()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Server Name: ")
        Dim ServerName As String = Console.ReadLine()

        Dim sc As ServiceController = New ServiceController("W3SVC")

        sc.Stop()
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
        sc.Start()

        Console.Write("Press Enter to Exit")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a reference to `System.ServiceProcess` assembly by right clicking the project and clicking Add Reference... and get command line arguments passed to the `Main` method like this:

```
Imports System
Imports System.ServiceProcess
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading

Class RestartIIS
    Shared Sub Main(ByVal commandLineArgs() as String)
        Run(commandLineArgs(0))
    End Sub

    Public Sub Run(ByVal machineName as String)
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Server Name: ")
        Dim ServerName As String = Console.ReadLine()

        Dim sc As ServiceController = New ServiceController("W3SVC", machineName)

        sc.Stop()
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
        sc.Start()

        Console.Write("Press Enter to Exit")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This question seems to be an exercise, so not posting fully working code would have been more helpful, IMHO.

Comment: Mehrdad, when i tried to run this, vs is telling me that i can't call run within a shared method. 

"cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class"

Comment: @Tomalak: it was more like a scripting admin type question than homework. I don't think homeworks deal with services and these kind of stuff.

Comment: @judy: You should either make Run method Shared or use an object instance to call it.

Comment: Instead of using  a `Sleep` you can use `sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)`

Answer (score 0):

```
ServiceControl.Stop()
Do
    ServiceControl.Refresh()
    If ServiceControl.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped Then
        ServiceControl.Start()
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: A little explanation why this snippet of code answer the question would be helpful, not only for the person asking the question but also for people finding this question later on